# avoid declaring same data types in different structures

Tags: c++, c

I have 2 -3 structures declared  in my code and all these structures have some common data type. 
In our company its strict policy that we do not duplicate code . so I am wondering is there any way that i can declare these common data type in some function and use that function when we declare structure.

example

```
 struct_1
    {

    ... un common stuff

    // below are common declaration .. how would I declare below data type in some function and
// call it here to declare those data type
    unsigned char char_1;
    unsigned int int_1;
    std::vector< small_structure> small_struct;

    }

struct_2
{

... un common stuff

unsigned char char_1;
unsigned int int_1;
std::vector< small_structure> small_struct;

}

struct_3
{

... un common stuff

unsigned char char_1;
unsigned int int_1;
std::vector< small_structure> small_struct;

}
```

Comment: put the common data in a struct or class. Then have a single member of your new type in each struct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not create common struct then?

```
struct Common {
    unsigned char char_1;
    unsigned int int_1;
    std::vector< small_structure> small_struct;
}

struct struct_3
{
    ... un common stuff
    struct Common commonStuff;
}
```

Or if you use C++, you could inherit from common struct:

```
struct struct_3 : Common
{
     ... un common stuff
}
```

But do prefer composition over inheritance when possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can put all these structures in a header file(xx.h).When you need these structures,you can include these header files,such as ' include "xx.h" '